# UIScrollView zoom just with 2 Fingers

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift3, cgcontext

I want to build an App that enables you to draw in an image, while zooming in.

I have a working code that lets you draw into an image, but the problem is that I also want to zoom in. I need to find a way to zoom and move around with 2 Fingers and draw with 1 Finger.

I tried:

```
self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;
```

But the problem is that this disables the drawing.

I also tried to add an UIPanGestureRegognizer but that won't fit in the framework I prefer to use.

So I am asking for a way to make scrollView ignoring the 1 Finger gesture or a drawing Framework that supports zooming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `UIViewController` (or `UIView`, whatever you use for showing) as delegate for your recognizers. Then add `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` and return `YES` for your case or always if you don't have another recognizers.